# msbuild is failing at CheckAzureNet46Support for a webjob

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to build and publish web job via MSBuild and it is failing at

> '_CheckAzureNet46Support' with error  VerifyAzureNet46Support  -
>   [VerifyAzureNet46Support] C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4755,
>   7): Your hosting provider does not yet support ASP.NET 4.6, which your
>   application is configured to use.

I've published other projects as web job to this web app with no issue but intermittently this issue occurs, is it something with my configuration of web app.

MSBuild arguments used for build is

> /P:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true 
>   /P:PublishProfileRootFolder="%heckoutDir\BuildConfigurations\publishProfile"
>   /p:PublishProfile="WebsitePublishProfile"
>   /P:Password=WebsitepublishProfilePassword
>   /P:outputdirectory=Bin/Release

Comment: That's odd. Would be best if you could [share a minimal repo](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-git-repo-to-report-an-issue) that demonstrates issue.

Comment: @DavidEbbo It seems when the app service is running low on memory and parallel publishing happen this error occurs. I've cross checked the memory utilization and publishing operation time and they match.

Comment: Conceivable. I've never encountered this error. But avoiding to overload the VM is definitely a good thing

Comment: @DavidEbbo Agreed, for me QA environment's are hosted in shared App Service plan so I would ask the team to stop using the app while publishing.

Answer (score 0):

If the app service plan is having high RAM or CPU utilization this issue occurs.
To mitigate this you can Scale Up app service plan to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely this has nothing to do with the App Service plans. That analysis simply does not make sense.

Rather, a build-time check fails verifying whether the deployment target in Azure supports ASP.NET 4.6. This is done by performing an HTTP GET request to a hard-coded URL at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613106&clcid=0x409. If said request returns 200 OK, the check fails.

Therefore, the more likely explanation is that the support page in question was back up for a few hours by mistake. We had the same problem, but it seems to work now.

Comment: This behavior is confirmed by Azure Product Support team also.